# Why is the OpenLDAP daemon called slapd?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I understand that it stands for Stand-alone LDAP Daemon ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapd) and [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/slapd)). My assumption is that sldapd is more confusing so it was shortened to slapd, but I'm curious if there's anything more to it than that.

Answer (score 2):

The [SLAPD](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SLAPD) (Standalone LDAP Daemon) and SLURPD (Stand-alone LDAP update replication daemon) was originally developed within the long-running project that developed the LDAP protocol.
Today, many LDAP Server Implementations are derived from the same code base of the original SLAPD and/or evolutions of it.

University of Michigan

LDAP was co-developed by Tim Howes of the University of Michigan, Steve Kille of Isode Limited, and Wengyik Yeong of Performance Systems International, in 1993.

-jim